# readr forcing column type

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read in a CSV file - and am attempting to force the columns to be of a certain type. But the very last column gives me an error: "Error in is.list(col_types) : Unknown shortcut: g"

Any advice, please? Thank you!

```
library(readr)

# Create data frame & write it out:
temp <- data.frame(a = 1:1001,
                   mystring_b = c(rep(NA, 1000), "1"),
                   mystring_c = c(rep(NA, 1000), "2"))
write.csv(temp, "temp.csv", row.names = F)

# Grab its names:
temp_labels <- names(read_csv("temp.csv", n_max = 0))

# Specify data type - for each column:
labels_type <- ifelse(grepl("mystring", temp_labels), "numeric", "guess")

# Reading in while forcing column types:
temp <- read_csv("temp.csv", col_types = labels_type)

# Error in is.list(col_types) : Unknown shortcut: g
```

Comment: What you are passing in to the `col_types` argument doesn't seem to match what the documentation says it is expecting. Have you checked the documentation yet to verify how you are specifying column types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an excerpt of the description of the `col_types` from the help page `?read_csv`:

> `col_types`
>
> ...
>   Alternatively, you can use a compact string representation where each character represents one column: `c` = character, `i` = integer, `n` = number, `d` = double, `l` = logical, `D` = date, `T` = date time, `t` = time, `?` = guess, or `_`/`-` to skip the column.

So, as the error message says, `"g"` is not an accepted shortcut. You should use `"?"` instead.

Also, while `read_csv` seems to be luckily taking the first character from your `"numeric"` specification, to be safe you should probably use `"n"` to match the documentation. In fact, if you look at the examples, the intent is to use a single string, not a vector of strings with length > 1, as the specification. Again, you're lucky if your method is working otherwise, but best to match the documentation, something like this:

```
labels_type <- paste(ifelse(grepl("mystring", temp_labels), "n", "g"), collapse = "")
```

Comment: Thank you! I adjusted my labels_type as follows - and it worked: labels_type <- paste(ifelse(grepl(excel_categ_name, labels), "n", "?"), collapse = "")